# How to set the return value of a get request in an unit test?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to set the return value of a `get` request in python in order to do a unit test, which tests if the `post` request is called with the correct arguments. Assume I have the following code to test

```
# main.py
import requests
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def function_with_get():

    client = requests.session()
    some_data = str(client.get('https://cool_site.com').content)

    return some_data


def function_to_test(data):
    for user in User.objects.all():
        if user.username in data:
            post_data = dict(data=user.username)
        else:
            post_data = dict(data='Not found')

    client.post('https://not_cool_site.com', data=post_data)


#test.py
from unittest import mock
from unittest import TestCase
from main import function_with_get, function_to_test

class Testing(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('main.requests.session')
    def test_which_fails_because_of_get(self, mock_sess):
        mock_sess.get[0].return_value.content = 'User1'

        data = function_with_get()
        function_to_test(data)

        assertIn('Not Found', mock_sess.retrun_value.post.call_args_list[1])
```

This, sadly, does not work and I have also tried to set it without `content`, however, I get an error **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'content'**

What would be the correct way to set the `return_value` of the `get` request, so that I can test the arguments of the `post` request?

Comment: Have you tried get without `[0]`? If you want to make multiple gets with different results, check `side_effect` and creating your own MagicMocks.

Comment: Removing `[0]` does not end up helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you almost have it, except you're missing the return value for `session()` - because `session` is instantiated to create the `client` instance. I think you can drop the `[0]` too.

Try:

```
mock_sess.return_value.get.return_value.content = 'User1'
```

Comment: Well... that missing `return_value` costed me a couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try with .text because this should work for strings.

```
s = requests.Session()

s.get('https://httpbin.org/cookies/         set/sessioncookie/123456789')
r = s.get('https://httpbin.org/    cookies')

print(r.text)
```

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/